# iOS alert "The printer is low on toner."

Tags: ios, printing, alert

Every time I print to my laser printer via iOS, I then need to dismiss the alert:

[image: The printer is low on toner.]

> Brother HL-L2360D series
> The printer is low on toner.
> OK

I really don't care if the printer is "low on toner", as long as it keeps printing.

I've been getting this message for over a year, have not changed the toner, and it continues to print fine. So I'll ignore the message until the print quality is effected.

How can I disable this "The printer is low on toner." iOS alert?

Comment: Turn off the alert at the printer.

Comment: Is the Toner Light on, on the printer ?

Answer (score 2):

Most printers issue alerts about low toner. There may be a method of turning it off on the printer itself; or changing the threshold for when the alert triggers.

This can usually be controlled on a physical control panel on the device; or a web interface; or a Utility app.

Printers will also usually show a % indicator for how much toner is left. You can then see whether the printer is indeed getting low on toner. If it is still at a high percentage, then this may warrant further investigation.

It's always good to have a new cartridge on hand for when the toner does actually run out, which is of course when you most need it.